# how to create print preview of the document printed

Tags: c#, c++

I am developing a custom  pane which will show up when the user presses 'Print'. This custom pane need to have a print preview. Please tell me how to create dynamic print preview of a document/images,etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to provide a bit more information then this. At least tell us something about what language and frameworks you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the c# tag i guess that it's not a problem if you use .Net framework. In this case [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404294.aspx) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ MFC you have this already done and available for you by MFC framework.

In C# and .NET framework not sure what you can do with the printdocument class. I used devxpress xtrareports in many projects and it pays off very well. Users love the ribbon print preview and you really get stunning ms word like print preview UI with zero coding. except a call to myReport.ShowRibbonPrintPreview .